# wireless connection to usb

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I've got a test instrument that moves backwards and forward down a tank 100ft distance. This device has current a usb cable between the device and laptop. Does anyone know of a way this can be down wirelessly? Thought about print servers but I think they only work with printer and not designed for data transfer on testing equipment. 
Any one got any ideas? 
We were thinking about this device
http://www.everythingusb.com/cables-unlimited-wireless-usb-adapter-kit-15823.html

but they no longer stock these items and cannot see anything similar on the net.

Appreciate any ideas
Thanks
Brenden

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Wireless USB Device Server](http://www.silexamerica.com/products/device_servers/usb_device_connectivity/sx-ds-3000wan.html) is what you are looking for. It gives you the possibility to access USB devices over 802.11n Wireless and a 10/100/1000Base Ethernet.

Comment: Hi, thank you for advice, but how would the test equipment that travels down the tank connect to this device?

Comment: The test equipment is connected to the devices USB port and accessed via wifi from a computer. Maybe I misunderstood your needs. I assumed you want to avoid attaching a 100ft long USB cable to the test equipment...

Comment: ok I understand so you put the wireless server on the platform that the device is on and plug it into the usb port, then the pc/laptop will see the wireless server as a wireless device and communicate with the test device which is attached with the cable?

Comment: @BrendenWard: yes, thats the setup. On the pc you will have to install a software which allows the communication with the usb-device over the network andemulates a local usb poort...

Comment: That's brilliant and thanks for the information appreciated.

Comment: silex page not found...